# Notify Module doesn't force production domain

Tags: 7, notifications

I've just installed the [Notify Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/notify) and it works awesome, except for one thing that I can't seem to change or configure.

My site is being hosted across multiple names and there is a specific one I would like the Notify Module to use. When I receive notifications via email, I get a link to the content which was added/modified. It uses the same domain name that the user used when adding/modifying content, and I'd rather it use my production domain.

If a user uses our test domain, this is what I get:

`1. A Message of Security for the 2014 Holidays. Blog entry by John Doe`
`[Published]`
    `[ http://direct.example.com/Security-Message-Holidays-2014 ]`

I would much rather it use:

```
` [ http://www.example.com/Security-Message-Holidays-2014 ]`
```

What happened was that the user used `direct.example.com` instead of our production domain `www.example.com`. I would like it to report the changes as being made to the production domain, not the one that the changes actually occurred through.

Unfortunately, I have been unable to find any way of changing this.

Is there any way that I can force the Notify module to use the production domain instead?

Comment: What's your [`$base_url`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7)?

Comment: My `$base_url` is configured properly, I just checked. Good idea though @Mołot . It turns out that this may merely be a scare, and that there might not be an issue at all. After further investigation, I saw that all of the notifications came back as `www.example.com` aside from that one. It almost appears that the user creating a new `blog entry` may have used `direct.example.com` instead of `www.example.com` to add the new `blog entry`. I am still waiting for a response from this user. If this is the case, what should I do with this question? Close it? Remove it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't remove. Modify it and ask how to force using current / production domain instead of the one used during item creation. If that's what you need, that is.